# Get shipping price value on order confirmation (Prestashop)

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

for internal purpose i need to print the shipping price costs (4,90€) into a custom tracking script in these following pages

**checkout/_partials/order-confirmation-table.tpl** and **checkout/cart.tpl**

Why the code below works only into cart.tpl?

```
{$cart.subtotals.shipping.value}
```

P.S. 1.7.6.3

Thanks for help

[image: Order Confirmation]
[image: Cart Confirmation]

Answer (score 0):

It  is  because  that  variable  came  from the  CartController.php   if  you are in the order  area  you  should  call the  variable  $order  not  the $cart  variable.

Do   a

```html
<pre>{$order|print_r}</pre>
```

To  see what  you  will get.